# Unity Align prefab to top left (2D Game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my first game where obstacles (which are prefabs) are placed by a script into a scene. They are all different sizes in a 2D environment. I am placing them using this code below

```
Instantiate(normal1, new Vector3(x, y , 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

This works perfectly, except that I need all of the obstacles to be positioned from the top left. So if I would have 0, 0 for my x and y, only the obstacle's corner would be covering the 0, 0 position, not the entire thing. From the little I've worked with GUI elements, you can align to however you like. Is this the same with prefab, and if so, how? Or can you somehow move the origin of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about non-UI elements.

The easiest thing would be to give your objects a parent `GameObject` and arrange them in a way so the parent GameObject already has the pivot where you want it (the top-left corner). You do this by first positioning the (future) parent object correctly and then simply drag the child object into it in the hierachy (while it keeps its current position).

[image]

Then in your script you have to use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) in order to find the top-left screen corner position in the 3D world like

```
// an optional offset from the top-left corner in pixels
Vector2 PixelOffsetFromTopLeft;

// Top Left pixel is at 
// x = 0
// y = Screen height

// and than add the desired offset
var spawnpos = new Vector2(0 + PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.x, Screen.height - PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.y);

// as z we want a given distance to camera (e.g. 2 Units in front)
spawnedObject = Instantiate(Prefab, camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(spawnpos.x, spawnpos.y, 2f)), Quaternion.identity);
```

*Full script I used as example*

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Prefab;

    public Vector2 PixelOffsetFromTopLeft = Vector2.zero;

    private GameObject spawnedObject;
    private Camera camera;

    private void Start()
    {
        camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            // you don't need this I just didn't want to mess up the scene
            // so I just destroy the last spawned object before placing a new one
            if (spawnedObject)
            {
                Destroy(spawnedObject);
            }

            // Top Left pixel is at 
            // x = 0
            // y = Screen height

            // and than add the desired offset
            var spawnpos = new Vector2(0 + PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.x, Screen.height - PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.y);

            // as z we want a given distance to camera (e.g. 2 Units in front)
            spawnedObject = Instantiate(Prefab, camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(spawnpos.x, spawnpos.y, 2f)), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This will now always spawn the object anchored to the top left. It will not keep it this way if the camera moves or the window is resized.

---

If your question was about keeping that position also when the window is resized you can use the same code e.g. in an `Update` method (later you due to efficiency you should only call it when really needed / window actually was resized) like

```
public class StickToTopLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera camera;

    public Vector2 PixelOffsetFromTopLeft = Vector2.zero;

    private void Start()
    {
        camera = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        var spawnpos = new Vector2(0 + PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.x, Screen.height - PixelOffsetFromTopLeft.y);

        // This time simply stay at the current distance to camera
        transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(spawnpos.x, spawnpos.y, Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, transform.position)));
    }
}
```

This now keeps the object always anchored to the top-left corner also after resizing the window and allows to adjust its offset afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a thorough answer. This is exactly what I needed.